# How to Extend the End Date in a SQL Calendar Table?

Tags: sql, calendar

I have a report that, according to users, started miscalculating dates in one field in November 2015. After some digging around, I found that one of the tables the field referenced seemed to have an end date on 2015-10-31.

[image: Query and last five results]

The "D" field seems to represent the day of the week, with Sunday being day 1 and Saturday being 7.

Is there a way to extend the calendar so that it ends further into the future, for example 2049-12-31?

Comment: I doubt anyone could know how to help based on so little info.  The table you have shown, is that all the records it has, just 5?  What is the field holding 3,4,5,6,7?

Comment: My apologies, Fred. The records shown are the last five results of the query; I didn't think it would be helpful to paste all the records into the post.

Comment: No but could it be that you need a record for each day?  Maybe when your system was written records up to 31 Oct 2015 were added now we are past that date its starting to give incorrect data?

Comment: Judging by your new image I would say you just need to add more records to that table.  First you need to work out what `d` is.  If its always 1-7 could it be the day of the week?

Comment: Yes, "D" is day of the week and it is always 1-7.

Comment: Sounds to me like you have a system much like Dan has explained below.  Add the new years worth of records and it will probably come right.

Answer (score 0):

Our calendar table, for a variety of reasons, goes the the end of the current year.  We have written a query that adds a new year to this table.  This query takes care of most of the fields in that table.  It does not touch the holiday field.  That is updated manually through a web page.

We send ourselves reminders.  Starting in March, we send monthly reminders that we should think about adding another year.  After ensuring that the database segment has space, and that none of the definitions, such as fiscal periods, have changed, we run the query that adds a year.

Later in the year we start mailing ourselves reminders about the holidays.  Then we check to see if HR has declared them, and if so, update the records accordingly.

This meets our business requirements.  Yours will be different of course.